# Python: Comparing length of corresponding rows in two arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have two arrays of equal length, in each row is a list of tuples, I want to compare the length of the tuple list in corresponding rows and then snip the larger one so that it is the same length as the smaller.

Most of the numpy comparison functions deal with element wise comparison, though maybe I'm missing something obvious.

So far I have made two attempts, when I use a for loop I generate every i/j combination between the two arrays when I only want a one-to-one comparison.

In the other I do not get anything appended to the empty lists I created.

```
if len(i) in slice_ary1 == len(j) in slice_ary2:
    mat_ary1.append(i)
    mat_ary2.append(j)
elif len(i) in slice_ary1 != len(j) in slice_ary2:
    diff_r = abs(len(i) - len(j))
    max_l = max(len(i), len(j))
    max_i = max((i,j), key=len)
    min_i = min((i,j), key=len)
    row_norm = max_l - diff_r
    mat_ary1.append(max_i[0:(row_norm)])
    mat_ary2.append(min_i)

for i in slice_ary1:
    for j in slice_ary2:
        #print(len(i), len(j))
        if len(i) == len(j):
            matrix_1 = np.array(i)
            matrix_2 = np.array(j)
            #print(matrix_1,len(matrix_2))
            # create matrix for i and j
        elif len(i) != len(j):
            diff_r = abs(len(i) - len(j))
            max_l = max(len(i), len(j))
            max_i = max((i,j), key=len)
            min_i = min((i,j), key=len)
            row_norm = max_l - diff_r
            matrix_1 = np.array(max_i[0:(row_norm)])
            matrix_2 = np.array(min_i)
            print(matrix_1,len(matrix_2))
```

Comment: This is just a list problem.  Arrays with differing size elements are object dtype, and require the same iterative methods as lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I am understanding you correctly. Is this what you want?

```
import numpy as np

# Just an example
slice_ary1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1]])
slice_ary2 = np.array([['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b']])

# Store the common length of your initial arrays
n = slice_ary1.shape[0]
# Create empty arrays for the output
mat_ary1 = np.empty(n, dtype=object)
mat_ary2 = np.empty(n, dtype=object)

# Loop over rows
for i in range(n):
    # Compute the smallest length of the lists in each row
    l = min(len(slice_ary1[i]), len(slice_ary2[i]))
    # Copy the first `l` elements of each list to the output arrays
    mat_ary1[i] = slice_ary1[i][:l]
    mat_ary2[i] = slice_ary2[i][:l]

print(mat_ary1)    # => [[1, 2] [1, 2] [1, 2, 3] [1]]
print(mat_ary2)    # => [['a', 'b'] ['a', 'b'] ['a', 'b', 'c'] ['a']]
```

Comment: Thanks @Alberto Garcia-Raboso, I've implemented it and got the output I was looking for, and apologies for not being clearer in my initial question.